# Rails evaluate variable being passed to helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Is it possible to pass in the value of a variable prior to it being passed to a helper method in Rails.

For example, I have a base64_encode helper method the @base_url is just being passed in a string literal instead of being evaluated.

```
<%= base64_encode(#{@base_url} + '/helloworld.html') %>
```

Comment: remove `#{}` and just call whatever method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"#{ variable }"` is variable interpolation in a ruby string. So you have at least two options for building your string.

```
<%= base64_encode("#{ @base_url }/helloworld.html") %>
# or
<%= base64_encode(@base_url + "/helloworld.html") %>
```

Note that you need to use `""` for Ruby string interpolation instead of `''`.
Kansas City on Rails has a [short blog post](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/08/ruby-string-interpolation/) to see in a glance how string interplation can look like.